# Laptop won't boot with both memory slots used

Tags: laptop, upgrade, memory, sony-vaio

I'm currently trying to upgrade my old **Sony VAIO VGN-SZ1HP/B** to 2GB of RAM. It already had 1GB of Crucial RAM in one of its slots, and one empty. I checked on Crucial.com and it confirms that [each bank can hold 1GB of PC2-5300](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=VAIO%20VGN-SZ1%20Series).

The 1GB stick already installed was [this](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/partspecs.aspx?imodule=CT12864AC667), but Crucial's page recommended [this](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=0F9A6C07A5CA7304)... The two are **identical** from what I can make out, so I just ordered another one of the former. Unfortunately the machine refuses to even POST with both sticks installed.

[image]

If I remove the old RAM from **Slot 1** and replace it with the new RAM it runs fine.
If I leave **Slot 1** empty and put RAM (either stick) in **Slot 2**, it won't POST.

Basically it seems that **Slot 2** just isn't working properly.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this problem? Or perhaps has some experience with this sort of thing with Sony VAIOs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on the latest BIOS revision? If you're up-to-date there, it sounds like you have a defective motherboard and should have it replaced.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the machine already has the latest BIOS revision :(

Answer (score 0):

With most Sony Viao laptops, if you press and hold F2 while it is booting, that will get you into the bios screen, regardless of if the logo appears.  From there you can check the settings regarding both of your memory slots.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've already tried pressing and holding F2 (the usual route into the BIOS) and can confirm that I am unable to get into BIOS with RAM installed in slot 2.

Sony have just quoted me £790GBP to replace the motherboard(!) :(

Comment: Wow, that's a rediculous price, but not unexpected from Sony (having owned a Viao myself for a few years).  Better off just buying a new laptop if it came to that.

Answer (score 0):

I have this now and am troubleshooting.

1. Take battery out
2. Hold laptop upside down and press power button for 10 seconds to remove residual charge and static
3. Remove both RAM sticks and then replace just one in lower slot
4. Power up without battery in and screen should work

Comment: Is it really necessary to hold it upside down? I have done residual discharges without flipping it upside down.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a broken motherboard. That slot, I later learned from a previous owner, has never worked. Thankfully the one slot I was left with was able to support a 2GB stick, so I'm all good. Thanks.