# What's the maximum RAM a single slot can take in my Sony Vaio?

Tags: laptop, upgrade, memory, sony-vaio

I have a **Sony VAIO laptop** (VGN-SZ1HP/B) that unfortunately has only one memory slot working (see my previous problem [here](https://superuser.com/questions/101715/laptop-wont-boot-with-both-memory-slots-used)), and it's very annoying as I'm limited to 1GB of RAM. According to Crucial, my machine has a [maximum capability of 2GB (2x 1GB)](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=VAIO%20VGN-SZ1%20Series), but obviously I'm stuck with 1GB... as only one slot is working.

[image]

I was wondering... would it be possible to install a **single** 2GB stick into the **one** slot that is working? That would not exceed the maximum allowed by the machine, afterall.

Is there a chance it could work? Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Crucial link your laptop has an Intel 945PM chipset, which [Intel lists](http://ark.intel.com/chipset.aspx?familyID=22817) as supporting up to 4GB of RAM.  At work we have Intel 945 laptops (they may be a different revision of the 945 though) that handle 2x 2GB sticks of RAM fine.

So I'd say there's a good chance it will work, but of course no guarantees.

Comment: Hmmm. According to Sony's website, the chipset is actually Intel i945GM. :-/ http://support.vaio.sony.eu/computing/vaio/specifications/index.aspx?m=VGN-SZ1HP/B&l=en_GB

Comment: Hmmm. Some people here seem to have done it successfully. http://forum.notebookreview.com/showthread.php?t=296027&page=3

Comment: Hooray! You were absolutely right! 1x2GB installed and working successfully!

Comment: +1 to @shf301 for the Intel link.  (I have a different mboard and chipset, but could find these at the link)

Answer (score 2):

There is a chance it will work, as sometimes the maximum module size in official specs is set to the maximum size that got full (or any) testing even though the chipset and board theoretically support larger per port. But the chance isn't all that high unfortunately, so I suggest you try find reference to people trying the same thing - if people have it will no doubt be discussed in a forum somewhere whether it failed or not.

Depending on how healthy your finances are, you could always just take a chance - you are not going to break anything by putting too big a module in, it'll just not work if it doesn't like it (or will only see half the module).